# There is a blue dot to the left on my screen when im on safari on my Ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

Why does a blue dot appear only when im using safari on my Ipad? I havent seen it before and has anyone noticed that dot to the left of the screen on an Ipad?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Sharing a screenshot would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of such a mysterious blue dot before. In those cases it disappeared after a reboot of the iPad - so you might want to try that!

Comment: And,now the blue dot disappeared it doesnt show it might have been something that has happened to the Ipad.

Comment: Exactly - as far as I understand it is some kind of bug that disappear after a reboot. If the reboot worked for you, please mark this answer as accepted, so that others know that this can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice of rebooting it did help.

Answer (score 0):

This icon means that some  feature is requesting the microphone to be active. It's likely to be something in Accessibility, such as Voice Control, once you close all the apps it will go, no need to turn off the phone

Comment: Any reference for that?